# Script Integer getting prefixed with "

Tags: shell-script, quoting, java, arguments

I am running a jar file using a very basic shell script (I literally just need this to run on startup of a NAS). However, I am getting some rather unexpected behavior:

Script looks like this:

```
java -jar myJar.war --inputParam=10101
```

myJar starts up - then throws a `NumberFormatException` saying that `"10101` is not a valid number format. The question is: where is that `"` coming from? Anything I can try to avoid this behavior?

The exact same command works if I run it manually without a script since there's no `"` appearing.

Thank you kindly!

EDIT:
hexdump of the original file:

```
0000000   /   u   s   r   /   l   o   c   a   l   /   j   r   e   /   b
0000010   i   n   /   j   a   v   a       -   j   a   r       /   s   h
0000020   a   r   e   /   m   a   t   h   u   -   g   o   /   j   e   n
0000030   k   i   n   s   .   w   a   r       -   -   h   t   t   p   P
0000040   o   r   t   =   1   0   1   0   1  \r  \n
```

Thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: Maybe you can hack your way out of a bug by requesting `java -jar myJar.war --inputParam=10101"` instead (escaping the double quote character).

Comment: hexdump -C of the script file? maybe odd line endings or invisible characters sneaked their way in

Comment: Your file as a DOS text file. Try converting it to a Unix text file using `dos2unix` (or just retype it in a fresh file in a Unix text editor).  The `\r` at the end of the line would be part of the argument passed to `java`.

Comment: @Kusalananda recreating it seems to have worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is the carriage return at the end of the line in the script file (visible as `\r` in the output of `hexdump -C`). This is a DOS line-ending, but on Unix, the carriage return would be part of the argument to `java`.

The error message would have said `"10101"` (Java would quote the string that it had difficulties interpreting in the message), but since the carriage return returns the cursor to the start of the line while printing it, the last `"` would have been printed at the beginning of the line, which made  the error message look a bit weird.

Retyping the script in a Unix text editor, or running `dos2unix` over the original file, would solve this.

Also note that a script should have a `#!`-line at the top.  For example, inserting `#!/bin/sh` as the script's first line would make the the script run with `/bin/sh` as its interpreter.